# How can i fetch Google Analytics data into cassandra using Nifi?

Tags: google-analytics, cassandra, google-analytics-api, apache-nifi

I want to fetch my website's google analytics data into cassandra using Nifi , is there any way for it?

Comment: Im not sure what nifi is but maybe you can make it by steps, 1) query with a python script using the api 2) export to csv 3) upload the data to cassandra.  http://www.ryanpraski.com/python-google-analytics-api-unsampled-data-multiple-profiles/

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use [InvokeHttp](http://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.4.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.InvokeHTTP/index.html) to query the Google Analytics data (perhaps with a [POST to batchGet](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet)), or you could use [ExecuteScript](http://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-scripting-nar/1.4.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.script.ExecuteScript/index.html) and include the Java API driver/JAR in your Module Directory path. Once you get the response(s), there are many processors you can use for any transformation of the data, including [ReplaceText](http://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.4.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ReplaceText/index.html) for generating a CQL statement to insert the data. Then you can send the statement(s) to [PutCassandraQL](http://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-cassandra-nar/1.4.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.cassandra.PutCassandraQL/index.html) for ingest into Cassandra.